# Set the name of image before inserting into the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am saving news' pictures in my file system and also saving the path in my mysql database. But I want to save the file by setting the name in my discretion and not the file name that has been set by the uploader. I want this to prevent the possible duplication of file name in my directory. I was thinking of saving them with a unique number on it.

Send file:

```
$target_dir_image = "../upload/image/";
$target_file1 = $target_dir_image. basename($_FILES["nimg"]["name"]);
    $move_images1=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["nimg"]`["tmp_name"],$target_file1);
// after connect the db
$nimg2=$target_file1;
```

Comment: Man can you tell us in points what do you want ? I could not understand.

Comment: Yes, I want save picture of user that uploaded in directory but base the structure my name not name of file in user hard, Because maybe another user for register news upload file and name of his/her file same as before user, due replace my be occur and  picture of Previous news my be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the `basename()` in your `$target_file1` variable, assuming that you already have a way to generate a new file name.

```
$newfilename = "YourNewGeneratedFilename.png";

$target_dir_image = "../upload/image/";
$target_file1 = $target_dir_image.$newfilename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["nimg"]["tmp_name"],$target_file1);
$nim2 = $target_file1;
```

Then on your query

```
if($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (image,path) VALUES (?,?)")){
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$newfilename,$nim2);
  ...
```

But if you don't have any, you can use the time to generate a new and unique filename (increasing the chance of not uploading the same file name, but I would still prefer a unique id to be added at the end of your file name).

Generate a new file name, along with the time it was uploaded:

```
$file = explode(".",$_FILES["nimg"]["name"]); /* STORE THE UPLOADED FILE NAME */
$extension = pathinfo(stripslashes($_FILES["nimg"]["name"]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION); /* STORE THE FILE EXTENSION */
$extension = strtolower($extension);

$timenow = date('his'); /* GET THE TIME NOW */
$count = count($file);  /* COUNT HOW MANY STRINGS HAVE BEEN PRODUCED */
$count = $count - 1; /* TO REMOVE THE EXTENSION ON THE COUNT */
$newfilename = ""; /* ESTABLISH A CLEAN VARIABLE */

for($x = 0;$x<$count; $x++){
  $newfilename .= $file[$x]; /* STORE THE EXPLODED STRING TO THE CLEAN VARIABLE */
} /* END OF FOR LOOP */

$newfilename = $newfilename."_".$timenow.".".$extension; /* PUT THE TIME AT THE END OF THE FILE NAME */

/* ...PUT HERE YOUR UPLOAD AND INSERT QUERY CODE... */
```

Comment: @JamalAzizbeigi - if my answer did help you, you can upvote my answer or accept it as the correct answer.